# Get resources in converter?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

What is the best way to get resource string or drawable in convert method of MvxConverter?
Can I access to current context or I have to manage static tracking?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to get resource string or drawable in convert method of MvxConverter?

There are some standard bindings that get access to resources, e.g.

- [MvxImageViewDrawableTargetBinding.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxImageViewDrawableTargetBinding.cs)
- [MvxImageViewImageTargetBinding.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxImageViewImageTargetBinding.cs)

There's also at least one example of using resources in a custom binding:

- [FavoritesButtonBinding.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Bindings/FavoritesButtonBinding.cs)

You could do similar code in an `MvxValueConverter` rather than in a custom binding if you would prefer it (but that converter would **not** then be usable across multiple platforms).

> Can I access to current context?

You can normally get access to Android `Context` objects using `Mvx.Resolve<T>` on:

- [IMvxAndroidGlobals.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid/IMvxAndroidGlobals.cs)
- [IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid/Platform/IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity.cs)

For i18n text cross-platform alternatives to Android strings are also available - from Vernacular and from Mvx - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n21-internationalisation-i18n-n1-days.html

> I have to manage static tracking?

No idea what this is. Sorry

Comment: There's also a little intro on custom bindings in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/custom-bindings-in-mvvmcross